# Browserify does not make require available

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, require, browserify

I am building a webapp with node.js and express.

I want to use Browserify to make my local modules available in the browser.

My app is structured like this:

```
├── app.js
├── lib
│   ├── controller
│   │   ├── home.js
│   │   └── mixer.js
│   ├── model
│   │   ├── command.js
│   │   ├── control.js
│   │   ├── room.js
│   │   └── user.js
│   └── view
│       ├── error.jade
│       ├── index.jade
│       ├── input.jade
│       ├── layout.jade
│       └── room.jade
├── package.json
└── public
    ├── images
    ├── scripts
    │   ├── app.js
    │   ├── command.js
    │   ├── index.js
    │   ├── room.js
    │   └── user.js
    └── styles
        └── styles.css
```

I have a local module called `Control`:

```
module.exports = function() {
  var control = {};

  control.command = false;
  control.create = false;
  control.last = 0;
  control.room = false;
  control.state = 2;
  control.time = 0;

  return control;
};
```

I used Browserify to create a file `public/scripts/app.js` by running the command:

`browserify -d lib/controller/home.js > public/scripts/app.js`

`home.js` requires `lib/model/user.js` which requires `lib/model/control.js`, so it should be available in in the compiled script.

In my `lib/views/layout.jade` file, I load this script:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title cosette #{name}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.6.0/bootstrap-table.min.css')
    script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js')
    script(src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js')
    script(src='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    script(src='http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js')
    script(src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js')
    script(src='/scripts/app.js')

    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/styles/styles.css')
  body
    .container-fluid
      .page-header
        h1
          a(href='/')#title cosette
          a(href='/room/' + name).small#name= name

      block content
```

Then, in my `lib/views/index.js` file, I import the the `index.js` file from `public/scripts`:

```
extends layout

block content
  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-6
      #notifications.list-group

    .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-6
      .input-group
        input(type='text')#room.form-control
        span.input-group-btn
          button(type='button')#create.btn.btn-default Create

      #rooms.list-group

  // Activate page
  script(src='/scripts/index.js')
```

Finally, in my `public/scripts/index.js` file, I attempt to use `require` to create a `Control` instance:

```
var control = require('./lib/model/control.js');

var socket = io();

var rooms = {};

var update = function() {
  $('#rooms').empty();

  for (var roomIndex in rooms) {
    var room = rooms[roomIndex];

    $('#rooms').append('<a href="/room/' + room + '" class="list-group-item">' + room + '</a>');
  }

  socket.emit('control', control);
};

// Control
$('#create').click(function() { control.create = $('#room').val(); });

// Input
socket.on('rooms', function(message) { rooms = message; });

setInterval(update, 1000);
```

However, when I attempt to load this page, I get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

I have looked on Stack Overflow and elsewhere at other issues with this error, but have not been able to fix the problem. What should I do?

My code is visible on Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/davidystephenson/cosette/src

Comment: The path `./lib/model/control.js` doesn't exist from `public/scripts/index.js`.

Comment: How do I import my control model then?

Comment: `../../lib/model/control.js`. Did you browserify your public `index.js`?

Comment: I browserified starting from `lib/controller/home.js`. It doesn't import `lib/view/index.js`, but that view does import the exported browserify script in the browser. I'm clearly going about this the wrong way, but I'm not sure how I should handle this type of structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browserify creates self-contained bundles, without exposing anything to the global namespace unless you use the --standalone flag, in which case *only* the library's name gets a global binding.

If you're trying to use its `require` function outside of the app.js bundle: you plain can't, that's now how the bundling works.

What you'd normally do instead, is write all your scripts in commonjs style (including the underscore/jquery/etc requirements!) and then create the bundle. If you then want `require('jquery')` to actually use a jquery that's already availabe on your page, you use something like `browserify-global-shim` to make sure that while browserify is bundling, it simply replaces any `require('jquery')` it sees with the appropriate "this-is-going-to-be-a-working-global-variable" that you tell it to, like `jQuery` or `$`.

Comment: I thought I was doing that by bundling `lib/model/control.js` through `/lib/controller/home.js` and then importing that in the browser. Can I use browserify to expose local modules to the browser? What tool can I use to do that?

Comment: you just say "browserify this one file" and it'll then discover the entire dependency chain and bundle everything in. So you don't bundle "multiple files", you just say "bundle, using file X as starting point, and then just add things as you find them". Say your main file in commonjs format is called "base,js" and it requires a million things and further files, you still only say "browserify base.js", because browserify will find everything it needs to bundle in for the entire app to work.

Comment: I did do that. I only browserified one file, `lib/controller/home.js`, which requires `lib/model/user.js`, which requires `lib/model/control.js`. The problem is, my browser won't let me require anything.

Comment: right so why would you be able to further require anything? The point of the bundle is that it is "done", you don't require anything more, everything's self-contained and closure-wrapped, so there is nothing for you to require in further yourself. It's already been taken care of. You can't just call `require` in your `public/scripts/index.js` and expect it to work, Browserify doesn't give you one in the slightest. Instead, you need to browserify that `index.js` instead, so that it can create a bundle in which that requirement is taken care of.

Comment: Oh, so I browserify the script that the browser calls in the HTML? This is different than I thought the tutorials I read worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you will anytime in future need some of the functions defined in code converted by **browserify** to be visible and usable in the browser, prepend them with `window.`. By this you will add them into window scope and browser will be able to see them and use them outside of the bundle.

```js
"use strict";

window.greeting = function(name) {
  alert("Hello " + name);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="dist/js/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Greeting page</p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    greeting('Tom');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```